# There is something wrong with my css of full calendar. Width auto is not responding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Full Calendar to show some events dates but having problem with widht value. I want it to be able to work properly at minimum 1024x768 resolution and other bigger screen sizes ( such as 1366x768 sized )  I tried quoting every width value in fullcalendar.css, enabling, disabling all css files one by one, inserting inline styles. Somebody advised working with bootstap responsive but it didn't gone well either. Right now i can see my calendar perfect in 1024x768 resolution but in  bigger resolutions there is a gap between calendar and right tables. I used chrome's tool inspect element and it says there is nothing on that empty area such as margin or padding.

my header is:

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <!-- CSS FILES -->
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/default/css/all-ie-only.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/css/fullcalendar.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/css/fullcalendar.print.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/default/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- END CSS FILES -->

    <!-- JS FILES -->
    <script src="/assets/default/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/assets/default/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/assets/default/scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/assets/default/scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <!-- END JS FILES -->

    <title>Permission System</title>
</head>
```

[Here is a copy of my style.css:](http://speedy.sh/uXndZ/style.css)

and my Full Calendar div:

```
<div style="min-width: 45%; width: auto; float: left; margin-left: 0px;" id="calendar" ></div>
```

Please help I'm about to go crazy!

I can send you teamviewer info if you think it would be easier to understand.

[All codes about css and some pics](http://www.speedyshare.com/zenpp/all-css-tpl-and-pics.rar)

Comment: This is not going to help. Post all styles which are in question of altering the troublesome element. Also post the computed styles from your dev-tools. Without this nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Just a vague guess from the code we see here: The `float:left;` might be the reason.

Comment: [HERE](http://speedy.sh/zenpp/all-css-tpl-and-pics.rar)
I also added some pics about where is the gap and how it looks on 1024x768

Comment: float might be the reason but it is not looking proper without float either

Comment: Why is your fullcalendar css and fullcalendar print css without any media=screen or media=print. Including print after main css will over ride rules in main css used in print css.

Comment: I faced same problem. and I found the solution struggling after one day. style.css of my template containing a fullcalender code that starts its class with fc- remove that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take fullcalendar.print.css out and make sure you have full calendar css and js only to rule out any print css issues.
The print css should only be incuded for print media and not for screen.
Have a look at [FullCalendar Source on this page](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) I cant find any reference to print.css in the header.